# ¿Como insertar las imágenes siguientes en página de Wordpress, de manera que en cada Patrocinio o Fila de Imágenes se tenga un tamaño diferente?

Tags: html5, css3, wordpress

Quisiera pasar estas imágenes, a Wordpress de manera que cada Fila de Imágenes o patrocinio tenga definido con CSS un tamaño distinto:

Ejemplo: Fila de Imágenes de Patrocinio 1: width: 300px; height: 225px ;

Ejemplo: Fila de Imágenes de Patrocinio 2: width: 200px; height: 125px ;

Ejemplo: Fila de Imágenes de Patrocinio 3: width: 400px; height: 325px ;

¿Como debo pasar el código html al editor de wordpress, que debo omitir de código posteado, y en que parte debó colocar el código CSS para asignar los tamaños?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>Ejemplo de imágenes</title>
   <style type="text/css">
    * { text-align: center; }
      h1 { font-family: arial; text-align: center;}
      p { font-family: arial; text-align: justify; margin: 25px;}
      img {width: 300px; height: 225px ; margin: 10px; }
   </style>

</head>
<body>
   <h1>Album de imágenes de ejemplo</h1>
   <p></p>

     <p>Patrocinio 1</p>
     <img src="http://foroamexcap.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/CMIC_Fondo-de-fondos_logo_baja-e1488219473944.jpg" alt="imagen1">
     <img src="http://foroamexcap.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/LOGO-MV-e1488219523437.jpg" alt="imagen2">
     <img src="http://foroamexcap.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Nafin_logo_1-e1488219676293.png" alt="imagen1">
     <br>

     <p>Patrocinio 2</p>
     <img src="http://foroamexcap.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/SP-Global.jpg" alt="imagen2">
     <img src="http://foroamexcap.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Creel_logo-nuevo.jpg" alt="imagen1">
     <img src="http://foroamexcap.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Piedmont-blue.jpg" alt="imagen2">
     <br>

     <p>Patrocinio 3</p>   
     <img src="http://foroamexcap.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Asgard.jpg" alt="imagen1">
     <img src="http://foroamexcap.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Asgard.jpg" alt="imagen2">
     <img src="http://foroamexcap.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/FAZENDA-LOGO-2.jpg" alt="imagen1">
     <img src="http://foroamexcap.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Grupo-IGS_logo.jpg" alt="imagen1">
     <br>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tendrías que envolver cada una de tus filas en un contenedor de tal manera que pudieras darle una clase en común a cada uno de los elementos contenidos en éste.

Luego en tu css le asignarías ancho y alto a las `img` dentro de la clase

```css
* { text-align: center; }
      h1 { font-family: arial; text-align: center;}
      p { font-family: arial; text-align: justify; margin: 25px;}
      img {width: 300px; height: 225px ; margin: 10px;float:left }

.patrocinio1, .patrocinio2, .patrocinio3 {
 clear:left;
 float:left;
}

.patrocinio1 img {
   width: 300px; height: 225px ;
}

.patrocinio2 img {
   width: 200px; height: 125px ;
}

.patrocinio3 img {
  width: 400px; height: 325px ;
}
```

```html
<h1>Album de imágenes de ejemplo</h1>
   <p></p>
  <div class="patrocinio1">
     <p>Patrocinio 1</p>
     <img src="http://foroamexcap.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/CMIC_Fondo-de-fondos_logo_baja-e1488219473944.jpg" alt="imagen1">
     <img src="http://foroamexcap.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/LOGO-MV-e1488219523437.jpg" alt="imagen2">
     <img src="http://foroamexcap.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Nafin_logo_1-e1488219676293.png" alt="imagen1">
  </div>     
     <br>
     
  <div class="patrocinio2">
     <p>Patrocinio 2</p>
     <img src="http://foroamexcap.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/SP-Global.jpg" alt="imagen2">
     <img src="http://foroamexcap.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Creel_logo-nuevo.jpg" alt="imagen1">
     <img src="http://foroamexcap.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Piedmont-blue.jpg" alt="imagen2">
     <br>
  </div>

  <div class="patrocinio3">
     <p>Patrocinio 3</p>   
     <img src="http://foroamexcap.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Asgard.jpg" alt="imagen1">
     <img src="http://foroamexcap.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Asgard.jpg" alt="imagen2">
     <img src="http://foroamexcap.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/FAZENDA-LOGO-2.jpg" alt="imagen1">
     <img src="http://foroamexcap.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Grupo-IGS_logo.jpg" alt="imagen1">
     <br>
  </div>
```

Esto se puede hacer de muchas maneras. El div puede ser un span, o puede ser tu mismo elemento `p` si éste envolviese a las imágenes. En vez de clase puede ser un id, y así sucesivamente. El código que te pongo es sólo una manera más.

**EDIT** añadí un estilo para que las imagenes se puedan alinear horizontalmente, eso si es que su ancho lo permite.

Comment: de acuerdo, gracias, una pregunta: ¿Como hago para que salgan en filas las imágenes y no en una sola columna? Esto me pasa en al pasar el código a wordpress

Comment: Puedes probar darles estilo `float: left;`

Comment: @ArmandoArellano edité mi respuesta. Prueba cómo te resulta.